# How to remove an html element according to its contents with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

If I have some html like this.

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li>
  <a href="pageGreen">
   pageGreen
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="pageBlue">
   pageBlue
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="pageRed">
   pageRed
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="page1">
   page1
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="page2">
   page2
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="page3">
   page3
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

How would I remove the entire LI element for pageGreen and pageBlue only, using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this could work

$("a[href='pageGreen']").parent().remove();

Comment: much better than my attempt (im a jQuery noob) :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like....

```
$("li a").each(function() {
if($this).html() == "pageGreen" || $(this).html() == "pageBlue") {
$(this).closest("li").fadeOut();
} 
});
```

Might need tweaking

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary traversal / comparisons. You'd be going through each li and then each a. It makes more sense to start with the a and then work outward/upward.

Comment: yeah, after seeing your suggested answer I totally agree. Much prettier.

Answer (score 1):

Try [jQuery’s `:contains()` selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text):

```
$("li:contains(pageGreen), li:contains(pageBlue)").remove();
```